# Installing AIX 7.2 from two iso files, using QEMU under CentOS 8

Tags: centos, qemu, aix, vmware

I'm trying to install AIX 7.2 having it on two iso files, virtualizing with QEMU version 4.2.0. I've created a disk file using the following command:

`qemu-img create -f qcow2 hdisk0.qcow2 20G`

Then I ran the following command to start the VM (the iso file names are aix_v72.iso and aix_v72_2.iso):

`qemu-system-ppc64 -cpu POWER9 -machine pseries -m 2G -serial mon:stdio -drive file=hdisk0.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -drive file=aix_v72.iso,media=cdrom -drive file=aix_v72_2.iso,media=cdrom -d guest_errors -prom-env "input-device=/vdevice/vty@71000000" -prom-env "output-device=/vdevice/vty@71000000" -prom-env "boot-command=dev / 0 0 s\" ibm,aix-diagnostics\" property boot cdrom:\ppc\chrp\bootfile.exe -s verbose"`

The installation process seemed to be good, but after I chose the language and default install settings, the Overwrite Installation Summary menu showed no available disks and then I saw an error "Not enough disk space selected to contain the operating system", despite I have specified the drive in the command.

What can be the possible reasons for that?

OS: CentOS 8, running under VMware

Comment: [This comment](https://astr0baby.wordpress.com/2018/11/04/running-aix-7-2-tl3sp1-on-x86_64-via-qemu-system-ppc64/#comment-8092) says *"You need to run AIX 7.2 TL3SP1 minimum, as the kernel in this Technology Level and Service Pack contains the needed virtio support"* -- do you know if your ISO files are 7200-03-01 or higher?

Comment: There looks to be more ideas at https://astr0baby.wordpress.com/2018/11/04/running-aix-7-2-tl3sp1-on-x86_64-via-qemu-system-ppc64/#comment-10230 as far as `... -drive file=disk.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi -device scsi-hd,drive=drive-virtio-disk0 ...`